# Alternatives to scattering experiments

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, scattering

Scattering experiments have been a fruitful and efficient way to determine the particles that exist in nature and how they interact.

What are some of the other experimental techniques used to determine the particles that exist in nature and how they interact?

Are these experimental techniques as fruitful and efficient as scattering experiments?

Comment: e.g., see [this answer of mine](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/250400/what-are-the-next-generation-physics-experiments/250424#250424)

Comment: So, you're saying that the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon is not found using scattering experiements?

Comment: no, it is measured in muon rings (no scattering there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some examples of techniques that don't necessarily involve scattering:

-Mass spectrometry

-Bubble chambers

-Cherenkov detectors

All these techinques were fundamental in the developing of modern nuclear physics and some of them are widely used still today.